# How to make objects in Unity2D interract smoothly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello I am making a 2D game in c#, using Unity2D.

Game is basically tower stacking game where player is given random objects from array which they need to stack on top of each other. Objects spawns at the top of the screen with Body Type Kinematic and player can move it only on the x axis and when player lets go object, its Body Type changes to Dynamic and it starts to fall and lands on start platform or tower.

My problem is that when this new object lands on existing tower or start platform it does not land smoothly, it goes in the other object and sometimes bounces and that often tips over the tower.
And when these objects stay on top of each other, they are vibrating and  causing the tower to tip over.

Is there any way of making objects be stable and not go in each other when landing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Physics objects automatically do collision detection IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a well-known problem and limitation with all physics engines.

It's called stacking stability, and it always becomes a problem, if you have large enough amount of physics objects.

There isn't really a single simple solution, it's a combination of choosing the right physics engine, setting your object's properties correctly, and even putting in some custom code of your own that tries to circumvent some of the issues when possible (for example by disabling physics on elements that are too deep down on the stack, so we consider them "stable", until some point when the situation changes).

[I recommend reading (and watching) this, and from there, exploring wherever the links will take you.](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/11/06/havok-physics-in-unity/)

And as I said, keep in mind that this is ...a common problem, and sometimes hard to solve. In some complex cases (yours shouldn't be one of them, though), even impossible to solve.

(EDIT two days after the answer has been accepted, I should have written this right away, sorry) :

Oh, and I forgot (sorry about that, but hopefully you've already found out from some of the resources you read) the problem of the objects going into each other can also be influenced by some settings (max depenetration depth i think it's called in unity). Another thing that might help is outright custom code which will raycast from the object that's falling downwards, and when it detects a block at a certain distance (you'll probably want to check for distance about the size that the object can travel in 1 to 10 frames or so), it would momentarily disable the physics on the falling one, position it exactly on top of the block below, zero out the velocity, and then re-enable the physics on it. This would avoid the penetration problems, as well as the instability and vibrations that happen when the new block impacts the tower. If you, however, want the effect of that impact instability to be present in some way, you can then still manually add a physics force on the impacted block(s), and it will have the upside that you can set the size of that force yourself (instead of it being calculated from the block), meaning you'll have much more control about how significant that impact effect is, which could be very useful for game balance, since that effect is quite important for the difficulty of the game, and in general, you'll want to have this level of control over things that affect gameplay difficulty ;)

Comment: Thanks, really helped. I changed masses and added custom material with more grip and it seems to be fine now. In the future i'm still thinking of doing more with scripts.

Comment: (I added a bit into the answer, that I should have written there right away, sorry) @DāvidsVolohs